# Deleting all rows that have same name in a column

Tags: r, rows, data-wrangling

I'm looking to see how I can delete any rows that have a duplicate name. For example, I have a name in column A that has these:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| ABC123 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| X2X2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| X1XD-01 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| BC-56 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| BC-56 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| YUA09 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| GGO-09S | 0 | 1 | 2 |

Any name in column A that has a duplicate value, both of them are deleted, such that the rows are gone.

Goal:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X2X2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| X1XD-01 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| YUA09 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| GGO-09S | 0 | 1 | 2 |

What is the most efficient way to approach this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We can `group_by` the desired column and filter out all groups with `n()` >=2:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(A) %>% filter(n()==1)

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   A [4]
  A           B     C     D
  <chr>   <int> <int> <int>
1 X2X2        1     1     0
2 X1XD-01     1     0     0
3 YUA09       0     0     1
4 GGO-09S     0     1     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Count the frequency with `table` and select only those values with 1 row.

```
subset(df, A %in% names(Filter(function(x) x == 1, table(A))))

#        A B C D
#3    X2X2 1 1 0
#4 X1XD-01 1 0 0
#7   YUA09 0 0 1
#8 GGO-09S 0 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `duplicated` to create a logical vector

```
df1[!(duplicated(df1$A)|duplicated(df1$A, fromLast = TRUE)),]
        A B C D
3    X2X2 1 1 0
4 X1XD-01 1 0 0
7   YUA09 0 0 1
8 GGO-09S 0 1 2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c("ABC123", "ABC123", "X2X2", "X1XD-01", "BC-56", 
"BC-56", "YUA09", "GGO-09S"), B = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L), C = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L), D = c(1L, 2L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```